# Calling a sub from another using date variables in ACCESS vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to invoke a sub from another sub in Access and keep getting a "Compiler Error ByRef argument mismatch. I understand that it says the variable I am passing does not match with the one specified in the called sub. Here is my code. I have the variables firstDayOfStartMonth and firstDayOfEndMonth defined as dates and am passing them to the second proc deleteCurrentData(startDate As Date, endDate As Date).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub loadDataFromExcel()

Dim monthName1, monthName2 As String

Dim startMonth, endMonth, curMonth   As Integer

Dim thisMonday, rptStartDate, rptEndDate, firstDayOfStartMonth, firstDayOfEndMonth As Date    

thisMonday = Date - Weekday(Date, vbMonday) + 1

rptStartDate = thisMonday - 14

rptEndDate = thisMonday - 10

firstDayOfStartMonth = DateSerial(Year(rptStartDate), Month(rptStartDate), 1)

firstDayOfEndMonth = DateSerial(Year(rptEndDate), Month(rptEndDate), 1)

Call deleteCurrentData(firstDayOfStartMonth, firstDayOfEndMonth)

End Sub

Private Sub deleteCurrentData(startDate As Date, endDate As Date)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have the variables `firstDayOfStartMonth` and `firstDayOfEndMonth` defined as dates

Actually, it is not quite true!

When you're using this declaration

```
Dim thisMonday, rptStartDate, rptEndDate, firstDayOfStartMonth, firstDayOfEndMonth As Date
```

only `firstDayOfEndMonth` is type of `Date`, other values are `Variant`. Try to use this declarations instead

```
Dim thisMonday As Date, rptStartDate As Date, rptEndDate As Date, firstDayOfStartMonth As Date, firstDayOfEndMonth As Date
```

this will fix the problem.

**P.S.** the same thing with

```
Dim monthName1, monthName2 As String
```

and

```
Dim startMonth, endMonth, curMonth   As Integer
```

Change them to

```
Dim monthName1 As String, monthName2 As String
```

and

```
Dim startMonth, endMonth As Integer, curMonth As Integer
```

accordingly

Comment: + 1 True. Unlike VB.Net, in VBA you have to explicitly declare your variables else like you mentioned they will be declared as variants :)

Comment: Personally, it's very inconvenient, but we can do nothing with this:)